# Limiting the number of match collection elements in neo4j using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a big amounts of nodes that have outgoing relations to even bigger amount of nodes. I want to be able to
query for a limited amount of starting nodes, returning with it the related nodes, but the related nodes should also be limited in numbers.

Is this possible in neo4j 1.9?

For example create these nodes and have an auto index on name:

```
CREATE p = (bar{company:'Bar1'})<-[:FREQUENTS]-(andres {name:'Andres'})-[:WORKS_AT]->(neo{company:'Neo1'}) 
WITH andres 
CREATE (restaurant{company:'Restaurant1'})<-[:FREQUENTS]-(andres)-[:WORKS_AT]-(lib{company:'Library'}) ;

CREATE p = (bar{company:'Bar2'})<-[:FREQUENTS]-(todd {name:'Todd'})-[:WORKS_AT]->(neo{company:'Neo2'}) 
WITH todd 
CREATE (restaurant{company:'Restaurant2'})<-[:FREQUENTS]-(todd)-[:WORKS_AT]-(lib{company:'Library2'}) ;

CREATE p = (bar{company:'Bar3'})<-[:FREQUENTS]-(hank {name:'Hank'})-[:WORKS_AT]->(neo{company:'Neo3'}) 
WITH hank 
CREATE (restaurant{company:'Restaurant3'})<-[:FREQUENTS]-(hank)-[:WORKS_AT]-(lib{company:'Library3'}) ;
```

What I would like is something like:

```
START p=node:node_auto_index('*:*') 
MATCH p-[:WORKS_AT]-> c, p-[:FREQUENTS]-> f 
RETURN p, collect(distinct c.company), collect(distinct f.company) LIMIT 2;
```

To return 2 rows and have the collections limited to one, but without using the function on the collections, tried that on a large
data set and it becomes extremely slow. So some way to LIMIT the matches..

If this is not possible in neo4j 1.9, would there be a solution in neo4j 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try something like this:

```
START p=node:node_auto_index('*:*') 
RETURN p, 
     head(extract(path in p-[:WORKS_AT]->() : head(tail(nodes(path))))) as work_company,
     head(extract(path in p-[:FREQUENTS]->() : head(tail(nodes(path))))) as visit_company
```

The head function on the extracted path node should be lazy so it pulls only the first one from the pattern match

If you look at the profiling output you should see that it touches only the first node each.

Comment: Yeah this works. One thing I do not understand is why the tail is necessary and another question whould be: how could I get more than one result from the related set?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the *:* query triggers some very large operations in the indexing layer, rather than being lazy.. I would try something like this:

```
START p=node:node_auto_index('*:*') 
WITH p LIMIT 2
MATCH p-[:WORKS_AT]-> c, p-[:FREQUENTS]-> f return p, collect(distinct c.company), collect(distinct f.company)
```

Comment: That doesn't give me a limitation on the related nodes.

Comment: And you don't want to use functions on the collections, like `HEAD(COLLECT(c))` etc.?

Comment: No, because in the real world we have LOADS of related items giving us unusable performance

Comment: @wouter ah, you're right, thats semantically different. Could you run a profile on the original query, and look at the _db_hits field to see if it somehow pulls through a very large number of records? You can run that with "PROFILE START p=.." in the Neo4j shell.

Comment: @Wouter Note the difference between `WITH head(collect(c)) as h RETURN h.company` and `RETURN head(collect(c.company))`, i.e. the former collects nodes (cheaper) and hits property store once, the latter collects the properties, which is more expensive. The difference should be significant, though perhaps not significant enough for your dataset.